# Writing Server stored procedures in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to c# and am having a difficult time figuring this out,

```
public UserNotificationFeed GetNotificationFeed(TenantInfo tenant, List<int> notificationId)
{
    UserNotificationFeed userNotificationFeed = new UserNotificationFeed();

    string sql = "select " + NotificationFieldList + " from UserNotificationFeed where MsgId = @MsgId";

    Database databaseObj = SocialDB.GetDataBase(tenant.ConnectionString, tenant.ProviderName);
    DbCommand commandObj = databaseObj.GetSqlStringCommand(sql);

    databaseObj.AddInParameter(commandObj, "MsgId", DbType.Int64, notificationId );

    using (IDataReader reader = databaseObj.ExecuteReader(commandObj))
    {
       while (reader.Read())
       {
          userNotificationFeed = new UserNotificationFeed();
          this.PopulateObject(userNotificationFeed, reader);
       }
    }

    return userNotificationFeed;
}
```

What I want is that the

```
string sql = "select " + NotificationFieldList + " from UserNotificationFeed where MsgId = @MsgId";
```

to take a list of `MsgId`s passed on by a `List<int> notificationId`.

Any help is really appreciated .

Comment: That isn't a "stored procedure", btw - it is just a command. Not an important point - just a bit of terminology.

Comment: are you getting exceptions?is it not running

Comment: Random question: if there are multiple ids, your code currently only returns the **last** row. What did you intend to do in that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach, since the data is `int` (and therefore injection safe) would be to just use:

```
string sql = "select " + NotificationFieldList +
    " from UserNotificationFeed where MsgId in (" +
    string.Join(",", notificationId) + ")";
```

(and don't add the parameter)

If you want it to be fully parameterized, that is possible too, but harder (it requires a flexible number of parameters). There are tools that can help, though. For example, with [dapper](http://nuget.org/packages/Dapper) that would be:

```
var rows = connection.Query("select " + NotificationFieldList +
    " from UserNotificationFeed where MsgId in @MsgId",
    new {MsgId = notificationId}).ToList();
```

here dapper will automatically tweak the SQL and add the correct number of parameters. But: dapper won't work directly with your `IDataReader`-based `PopulateObject` method (since it has *already* populated some objects).